# Method for taking this inverse laplace transform

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

i am having trouble taking the answer to this problem that i found a book called "Differential equations with applications and historical notes":

$$
e^{-x} = y(x) + 2 \int_0^x\cos(x-t)y(t) dt
$$

First i took the Laplace transform:

$$
L[e^{-x}] = L[y] + 2 L[\cos(x)] L[y]
$$

$$
\frac{1}{p+1} = L[y](1+\frac{2p}{p^2+1})
$$

$$
\frac{p^2+1}{(p+1)^3} = L[y]
$$

Then i need to find the Inverse Laplace Transform, so i did partial fraction decomposition:

$$
\frac{p^2+1}{(p+1)^3} = \frac{a}{p+1} + \frac{b}{(p+1)^2}+\frac{c}{(p+1)^3}
$$

$$
p^2+1 = a(p+1)^2 + b(p+1) + c
$$

$$
p^2 + 1 = ap^2 + p(2a+b) + (a+b+c)
$$

it is clear that $a=1$, $b=-2$, $c=2$ therefore:

$$
L[y] = \frac{1}{p+1} - \frac{2}{(p+1)^2}+\frac{2}{(p+1)^3}
$$

But here i get stuck,

$$
y = e^{-x} + L^{-1}[\frac{2}{(p+1)^3}] - 2 L^{-1}[\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}]
$$

Any advice or methods that may help me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks, perhaps i should derive those quickly

Comment: @Amzoti Yes i agree, i just did it it was pretty simple, you may answer if you like for some points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following property of the Laplace transform

> $$ \mathcal{L}(x^nf(x)) = (-1)^{n} F^{n}(s).  $$

You can see that

$$ \mathcal{L}(x^2 e^{-x}) = \frac{2}{(1+s)^3}. $$

You can find the other one with the same technique.